# Rapid merges creates duplicate nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I run the following Node.js code against an empty database, a seemingly random number of nodes between 3 and 5 are created.  Is this a bug?

It's important to note that the requests are happening asynchronously.

```
for(i=0; i<15; i++) {
  db.query(
    'MERGE(test {name: "test"}) return test',
    function() { console.log(arguments); }
  );
}
```

db.query is just a simple abstraction for the cypher REST endpoint.

This is on Neo4j 2.0.0-M04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/831